# How do you pass a variable from a click function to another function's parameters in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need help on how to pass a variable from a jQuery click function to another plugin's function's parameters.  In the code below I need to pass the 'imagePathArray' from the click function to the to the images Parameter in the $(this).reel  .  Will this work?  So far I can not seem to get it to work.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.image-selector').click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Work out which image to display, amend the displaying image then load the rest and fade in.              
    whichImageInput = $(this).data('which');
    imagePathImages = $('#imageSequence-' + whichImageInput).attr('value');
    imagePathArray = imagePathImages.split(','); 
    totalFrames = imagePathArray.length;
    imagePath = imagePathArray[0];



    //alert(imagePathArray[0]);
    //alert(whichImageInput);
    $('#image').attr('src', imagePath).fadeOut('fast', function () {
        //DisplayImages(whichImageFolder);
        DisplayImages(imagePathArray[0]);
    });
  });



 DisplayImages('Kachina');

function DisplayImages(whichInput) {

    //function DisplayImages(whichFolder) {
    //var imagePath = 'images/' + whichFolder + '/';
    // Call this to destroy any existing reference before initialising...
    $('#image').trigger('teardown');
    // Needs a bit more thought when swapping between colours.          
    $('#image').fadeIn('fast', function () {


        $(this).reel({
            frames: totalFrames,
            //footage: 4,
            sensitivity: 70,
            saves: true,
            //path: imagePath,
            cw: true,
            hint: "Click and drag",
            clickfree: false,
            preloader: 20,

            images: imagePathArray
        });
    });
}
});
```

**EDIT**
Ok this is the code I have now using some of the suggestions from below. However I now am having to click the a.image-selector twice to populate the image onto the page.  It passes correctly the first time (tested via alert()), but the actual image in the  tag is not populating the first time. I am going to include my HTML too.
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('a.image-selector').click(function (event) {

```
    event.preventDefault();

    // Work out which image to display, amend the displaying image then load the rest and fade in.              
    // var whichImageFolder = $(this).data('which');
    //var imagePath = 'images/' + whichImageFolder + '/0001.png';
    whichImageInput = $(this).data('which');
    imagePathImages = $('#imageSequence-' + whichImageInput).attr('value');
    imagePathArray = imagePathImages.split(',');
    totalFrames = imagePathArray.length;
    firstImagePath = imagePathArray[0];

    //alert(imagePathArray[0]);
    //alert(whichImageInput);
    $('#image').attr('src', firstImagePath).fadeOut('fast', function () {
        //DisplayImages(whichImageFolder);
        DisplayImages(firstImagePath, $(this));
    });
});


function DisplayImages(whichInput, cntrl) {

    //function DisplayImages(whichFolder) {
    //var imagePath = 'images/' + whichFolder + '/';
    // Call this to destroy any existing reference before initialising...
    $('#image').trigger('teardown');
    // Needs a bit more thought when swapping between colours.          
    $('#image').fadeIn('fast', function () {
       // alert(imagePathArray);
        $(cntrl).reel({
            frames: totalFrames,
            //footage: 4,
            sensitivity: 70,
            saves: true,
            //path: imagePath,
            cw: true,
            hint: "Click and drag",
            clickfree: false,
            preloader: 20,

            images: imagePathArray
        });
    });
  }
 });//End doc.ready
```

HTML Below

```
   <div class="block">
        <div class="imgHolder">
            <img id="image" src="" height="448" width="360" />
        </div>
    </div>
  <!--Thumbs-->

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" class="image-selector" data-which="Kachina"><img src="images/smooshed150dpi/Kachina0001.png" width="150" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="image-selector" data-which="Lapis"><img src="images/Lapis/Lapis_Thumb.png" width="150" /></a></li>

    </ul>

        <input type="hidden" id="imageSequence-Kachina" value="images/Kachina/0001.png, images/Kachina/0002.png, images/Kachina/0003.png, images/Kachina/0004.png, images/Kachina/0005.png, images/Kachina/0006.png, images/Kachina/0007.png, images/Kachina/0008.png, images/Kachina/0009.png, images/Kachina/0010.png,
                     images/Kachina/0011.png, images/Kachina/0012.png, images/Kachina/0013.png, images/Kachina/0014.png, images/Kachina/0015.png, images/Kachina/0016.png, images/Kachina/0017.png, images/Kachina/0018.png, images/Kachina/0019.png, images/Kachina/0020.png,
                     images/Kachina/0021.png, images/Kachina/0022.png, images/Kachina/0023.png, images/Kachina/0024.png, images/Kachina/0025.png, images/Kachina/0026.png, images/Kachina/0027.png, images/Kachina/0028.png, images/Kachina/0029.png, images/Kachina/0030.png,
                     images/Kachina/0031.png, images/Kachina/0032.png, images/Kachina/0033.png, images/Kachina/0034.png, images/Kachina/0035.png, images/Kachina/0036.png" />

         <input type="hidden" id="imageSequence-Lapis" value="images/Lapis/0001.png, images/Lapis/0002.png, images/Lapis/0003.png, images/Lapis/0004.png, images/Lapis/0005.png, images/Lapis/0006.png, images/Lapis/0007.png, images/Lapis/0008.png, images/Lapis/0009.png, images/Lapis/0010.png,
                     images/Lapis/0011.png, images/Lapis/0012.png, images/Lapis/0013.png, images/Lapis/0014.png" />
```

Comment: I'm not quit sure what you mean. $(this) in DisplayImages is the control that raised the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the control that raised the event as a reference/variable to the function.

```
DisplayImages(imagePathArray[0], $(this));
```

The function will look like this:

```
function DisplayImages(whichInput, cntrl) {
```

and

```
$(cntrl).reel({
```

Comment: Your's is the one that has gotten me the closest. But I have to click the a.image-selector twice to get the imagePathArray to populate the    $(cntrl).reel({ images: imagePathArray}); Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quit sure but maybe I'm not having all HTML and the reel plugin.

This you have to check:
1. You have to integrate the click code in ' $().ready(function () {' because the DOM is not ready. 2. Why is the DisplayImages('Kachina'); still there? It will not work because it come for the function plus the parameters are not correct (missing cntrl).

Comment: But I think that is subjet for another question :-)

Comment: The click code is in the document.ready.  I just added it here. It is in my JS file.  The full HTML wasn't in this example. It is now.  I took out the DisplayImages('Kachina').  Wasn't being used.  Not sure what your last sentence means. In my Edit it is in there. Or did I put it in the wrong spot?  Thanks

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work. My "teardown" needed to be added to the click event not the DisplayImages function. Thanks for the help. Everything else you suggested works though. appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about making the imagePathArray a global variable.??

May be after the line

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

you can have

```
var imagePathArray;
```

this way `imagePathArray` will be available everywhere in the jquery namespace

Answer (score 0):

I got it working

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ $('a.image-selector').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// Work out which image to display, amend the displaying image then load the rest and      fade in.              
whichImageInput = $(this).data('which');
imagePathImages = $('#imageSequence-' + whichImageInput).attr('value');
imagePathArray = imagePathImages.split(',');
totalFrames = imagePathArray.length;
firstImagePath = imagePathArray[0];
$('#image').trigger('teardown');//MOVED TO HERE TO INITIALISE TEARDOWN ON CLICK.
$('#image').attr('src', firstImagePath).fadeOut('fast', function () {
    DisplayImages(firstImagePath, $(this));
});
 });


function DisplayImages(whichInput, cntrl) {

   //function DisplayImages(whichFolder) {
//var imagePath = 'images/' + whichFolder + '/';
// Call this to destroy any existing reference before initialising...

$('#image').trigger('teardown');
// Needs a bit more thought when swapping between colours.

$('#image').fadeIn('fast', function () {
   // alert(imagePathArray);
    $(cntrl).reel({
        frames: totalFrames,
        //footage: 4,
        sensitivity: 70,
        saves: true,
        //path: imagePath,
        cw: true,
        hint: "Click and drag",
        clickfree: false,
        preloader: 20,

        images: imagePathArray
    });
    });
  }
 });//End doc.ready
```